# Google Maps: Change default Embedded mapTypeId or use controls from Embedded API map on Javascript API map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Neither the embedded api nor the javascript api versions of Google maps will behave how I'd like, please help.

The embedded api doesn't allow me to set the default map view to hybrid through the url parameters. I've tried using &t=h but it blacks out the map.

The javascript api version doesn't allow me to set the default controls to the same overlay that the embedded version uses. Specifically, I'd like the address and a link to directions to display on the map (the control element in the upper left corner of an embedded api map). See the pictures for more clarification.

So the question:
Is it possible to change the default map type of an embedded api Google Map to 'hybrid' using any method? Please provide a complete link example if demonstrating with '&t=h' (does the parameter need to be in a certain location in the URL, ie. before/after some other parameter?).

OR

Is it possible to use the control overlay from an embedded api Google Map on a javascript api Google Map?

Embedded API (Desired controls, wrong default mapTypeId)
[image]

Javascript API (Desired default mapTypeId, wrong controls)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Success!

Using the embedded API, '&maptype=satellite' will work instead of '&t=h'.